# Ball Physics problem Python

Tags: python, physics, game-physics

I am trying to make a ball bounce within a box correctly, specifically handling corners at specific angles and handling a corner head on. I have a problem, because my ball keeps coming out of the box. I have this function that tells if my ball is out of the box and it handles corners and walls. The code is this:

```
    if ((self._x > self._Grid.getWidth()) or (self._x < 0)):
        print("RandomNode:outside paramaters: x! self._x = %s , self._velx = %s" % (self._x , self._velx))
    if ((self._y > self._Grid.getLength())  or (self._y < 0)):
        print("RandomNode:outside paramaters: y!")
    if ((self._velx + self._x) > self._Grid.getWidth()):
        diff = self._Grid.getWidth()-self._x
        self._velx *= -1
        if (diff == 0):
            self._x -= self._velx
        else:
            self._x+= diff
        tampered = True
        #print("eqn1: self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))

    if (self._velx + self._x < 0):
        diff = self._x
        self._velx *= -1
        if (diff == 0):
            self._x += self._velx
        else:
            self._x-= diff
        tampered = True
        #print("eqn2: self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))


    if ((self._vely + self._y) > self._Grid.getLength()):
        diff = self._Grid.getLength()-self._y
        self._vely *= -1
        if (diff == 0):
            self._y -= self._vely
            if (tampered == True):
                if ((self._velx * -1 == self._vely) or (self._velx == self._vely)):
                    self._x += self._velx
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn31:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
                else:
                    self._x += (self._velx - diff)
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn32:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
            else:
                tampered = True
                #print("eqn33:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))


        else:
            self._y+= diff
            if (tampered == True):
                if ((self._velx * -1 == self._vely) or (self._velx == self._vely)):
                    self._x += self._velx
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn31:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
                else:
                    self._x += (self._velx - diff)
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn32:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
            else:
                tampered = True
                #print("eqn33:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))

    if (self._vely + self._y < 0):
        diff = self._y
        self._vely *= -1
        if (diff == 0):
            self._y += self._vely
            if (tampered == True):
                if ((self._velx * -1 == self._vely) or (self._velx == self._vely)):
                    self._x += self._velx
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn41:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
                else:
                    self._x += (self._velx + diff)
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn42:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
            else:
                tampered = True
                #print("eqn43:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))

        else:
            self._y-= diff
            if (tampered == True):
                if ((self._velx * -1 == self._vely) or (self._velx == self._vely)):
                    self._x += self._velx
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn41:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
                else:
                    self._x += (self._velx + diff)
                    self._y += self._vely
                    #print("eqn42:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
            else:
                tampered = True
                #print("eqn43:self._x = %s , self._y = %s , self._velx= %s, self._vely= %s" % (self._x, self._y, self._velx, self._vely))
    return tampered
```

I don't know why it is not working. x and y are obviously its coordinates. Velx and Vely are its x and y velocities. Tampered is a Boolean that prevents the ball from moving normally and only being moved within check.

Here is my question. What is wrong with this code? OR....is there a template written in python somewhere on the net or where ever, or a code that you have used that does the exact thing I am trying to handle and do? Please revise the code at will, just let me know. Any links to this already solved would be great as well. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of writing 'this is not working' try giving a helpful description of what is actually happening. Do you get an exception somewhere? If so, what is it? Do you get results that you did not expect? If so, what are they?

Comment: good point. I get my error that it is outside the parameters. BUT, it is only outside the grid by one unit, then it corrects itself sort of.....It only happens maybe a hundred times in a 100000 movements

Comment: Just a few hints on making your code more readable. Don't use `== True`, it works just as well if you use `if tampered:` also, there is no need for `( )` around if statements and lastly, `if not diff:` is more readable then `if (diff == 0):`

Comment: Well, I'll make it look flashy when it is working. Thanks for the recommendations. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: It would also help if you can put a figure with a graphical description of the "erronous" trajectory you get

Comment: @gpu_drug.....If it was graphical , I would be able to see my own error. All of this is happening under the hood.There is no GUI. If I knew what was happening or where the ball was leaving the grid, I would have been more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rewrite this code. It is way too complex for the simple problem you're trying to solve.

**First**, a 2D motion of a ball is just 2 1D problems. You can completely separate X and Y. For example, hitting a corner is completely equivalent of hitting a wall in X axis + hitting a wall in Y axis. Hitting a wall in X just reverses the X velocity (and possibly loses some energy if you want to simulate that). Hitting a wall in Y reverses Y velocity.

**Second**, since the handling of X and Y is so similar, extract a method out of it

```
def handle_axis_movement(location, velocity):
    "returns updated location and velocity"
    ...

self.x, self.vel_x = handle_axis_movement(self.x, self.vel_x)
self.y, self.vel_y = handle_axis_movement(self.y, self.vel_y)
```

This will cut the amount of code (and bugs) in half.

**Third**, you don't have to treat diff==0 and diff<0 seperately. Both cases mean the ball hit a wall, and should reverse its velocity. Then you should correct the location to account for the fact that it couldn't have passed through the wall.

```
location += velocity
if location > max_bound:
    location = max_bound - (location - max_bound)
    velocity *= -1
if location < min_bound:
    location = min_bound - (location - min_bound)
    velocity *= -1
```

Comment: I like what you saying, but there is an issue why that doesn't work. I cant think of it now, cause I'm too tired, but I will respond in the morning with fresh eyes. This looks like a decent way to do it though.

Comment: I don't think 'velocity *= -1' will give a decent representation of a reflected velocity because only one component of the velocity (the 'X' or 'Y' in axis aligned 2d) should actually be time(sed) by -1.

Comment: Sorry ofri, you need to help him know what the reflected velocity should be... a 'not so trivial' problem with simple bounding squares... even without thinking that next week, TheChes44 wants to slowly rotate the square around in while managing the reflected velocities.

Comment: @Steve H - velocity is not a vector! its a 1D scalar. its just used to DRY in handling the 2 axes. it will actually do exactly what you wrote in your first comment.

Comment: Pardon me while I go take my foot out of my mouth. I see that now. That is elegant. I partially read it and thought velocity WAS a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be reinventing this wheel when [pymunk](http://code.google.com/p/pymunk/) does it for you so well. ;)

Comment: what does that do? How do I use it?

Comment: have a look, it's a 2D rigid body physics simulation. they have a demo app that goes with the library for you to mess around with the features.

Comment: what if I dont want it for graphical purposes....just under the hood if you get my drift. It really isnt a game, is there a way I can use their python code?

Comment: yeah no worries, the graphical part is only if u want to hook it up to a rendering engine. pymunk is happy for u to just input rigid body positions and get out their velocity at random time intervals. i think it's best if you check out the link and look at their demo to see how they do things. it's quite easy to setup and they have a friendly, responsive forum.

Comment: also, even if it isn't for a game, it's probably useful to see how your balls are drifting out of the box, so pymunk and pygame are naturally very useful for toying with rigid body colisions